# How this convolution integral is solved to obtain autocorrelation function of current for shot noise?

Tags: noise, convolution, autocorrelation

I am studying shot noise characteristics from [this](http://maxim.ece.illinois.edu/teaching/spring16/notes/lec06.pdf) source:

Here the author writes that autocorrelation function is given by:
$$R_I(\tau)=\bar{h}*h*R_Z(\tau)$$
where $R_Z(\tau)=q^2(\lambda^2+\lambda \delta(\tau))$ and $\bar{h}(t)=h(-t)$
now applying the value of $R_Z(\tau)$ in the integral we have
$$=q^2\lambda^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)h(s-t)\text{d}s\text{d}t+q^2\lambda\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)h(s-t)\delta(t)\text{d}s\text{d}t$$
$$=q^2\lambda^2(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{h}(t)\text{d}t)^2+q^2\lambda\bar{h}*h(\tau)$$
the second term I am able to derive as I know that
$$q^2\lambda\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)h(s-t)\delta(t)\text{d}s\text{d}t$$
$$=q^2\lambda\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)h(s)\text{d}s$$
however, I can not get that how:
$$q^2\lambda^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)h(s-t)\text{d}s\text{d}t$$
turns out to be
$$=q^2\lambda^2(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{h}(t)\text{d}t)^2$$
can somebody please help me out with this?

**PS:** As per the answer of Matt  L., as inner integral is independent of $s$ so I can do certain manipulations to get requisite output, however, I have a doubt here that I want to clear:
$$q^2\lambda^2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)h(s-t)\text{d}s\text{d}t$$
is precisely
$$q^2\lambda^2\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)h(s-t)\text{d}s\text{d}t$$
now repeating the steps as suggested in the answer I have:
$$q^2\lambda^2\int_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)\left[\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}h(s-t)\text{d}t\right]\text{d}s$$
I believe that the inner integral should be some function of $s$ let us say $f(s)$ and then we should have
$$q^2\lambda^2\int_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)f(s)\text{d}s$$
The reason I believe so is because $s$ may be constant for inner integral but outer integral needs $s$, how I can I simply replace $s$ without changing the outer integral limits and $\text{d}s$ in outer integral.

Also taking the answer's view:
$$q^2\lambda^2\int_{s=-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)\left[\int_{t=-\infty}^{\infty}h(s-t)\text{d}t\right]\text{d}s$$
we replace $s-t$ with some dummy variable $t'$, but if we do so, shouldn't the outer integral will change accordingly as it also contains $s$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bar{h}(\tau-s)h(s-t)dsdt&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(s-t)dt\right]\bar{h}(\tau-s)ds\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)dt\right]\bar{h}(\tau-s)ds\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)dt\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(s-\tau)ds\\&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)dt\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(s)ds\\&=\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(t)dt\right)^2\end{align}$$

The second equality is true because the inner integral is independent of $s$. Similarly, the integral of $h(s-\tau)$ in the third line is independent of $\tau$.

Comment: I have a doubt when you talk about second equality then you basically assume that $s$ to be constant and I assume that you replace $s-t$ with some dummy variable (let us say $t'$). However, I believe it will also affect the outer integral because that involves $s$ and also the limits of outer integral are from $s$ ranging from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I assume that you may have missed several steps which precisely I am trying to figure out.

Comment: @UserHuffmann: Since the inner integral doesn't depend on $s$ (because you integrate over the real line), it is constant and can be taken out of the integral over $s$.

Comment: can you please check my edited question wherein I have tried to be more precise about my doubt. I will be grateful. Thanks

Comment: @UserHuffmann: You can indeed see $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}h(s-t)dt$$ as a function of $s$. However, it should be easy to see that this function is actually constant. Just think about it as integrating over a function $h(-t)$ that is shifted by some parameter $s$. Regardless of the shift $s$, the result is always the integral over that same function, because shifting doesn't change the value of the integral (the area), as long as we integrate from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. Now, since we see that what you call $f(s)$ is actually a constant, we can take it out of the integral.

Comment: Now, I got your point. The limit in this expression from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is what is leading to this peculiar solution. Thanks